# Adding columns to table in draw.io/diagrams.net

Tags: tables, diagram, draw.io

I am using the current version of draw.io for Debian Linux (diagrams.net 17.2.1), and I want to make a table with a dozen or so columns. Selecting the **Table 1** item generates a three column table.

[image: Screenshot of the draw dot IO left-hand shape menu with "Table 1" highlighted]

When I select a cell or vertical group of cells, then select **duplicate**, it adds additional rows rather than additional columns.

[image: Screenshot of a three column table in draw dot IO with the right-most column highlighted]

**My question is** ***how do I add additional columns to the table?***

Answer (score 2):

Use the table re-dimensioning  menu in the ribbon:

[image]

One line is actually added to the default 3x3 table.The result after adding total 3 columns and 2 lines:

[image]